# Cannot use `$$` character in GitLab environment variables

Tags: environment-variables, gitlab, gitlab-ci, envsubst

Cannot use `$$` character in environment variables of GitLab CI.

I store my secrects in GitLab CI environment variables out of which one of my pass word string has $$ characters at the end (eg :Ab1ab$$). When i echo it out or use envsubst, the output will be Ab1ab$, stripping the extra $ on the end.

I tried using to surround the string in '',"" none of which helped. Saw some concerns on the gitlab community regarding the usage of $ character in the env variables, but could not find any workarounds for my exact problem.

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/27436

export VAR= 'Ab1ab$$'
echo $VAR=Ab1ab$

Comment: Have you tried to store your password like Ab1ab$$$$ ? The output will surely be what you need

Comment: @lago Carvatho Yes I did, It strips all the $$$$ and appends 1. Output is "Ab1ab1"

Comment: In bash, you can represent a `$` as `\$`. What output `Ab1ab\$\$` have?

Comment: @lago Carvalho, I got Ab1ab\ as the output

Comment: Haaa, sorry... I have no more ideas...

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty common problem with setting env variables in CI!  I have encountered it numerous times with CircleCI as well.  I have found great success with backslashes, typically, but I'm guessing you tried that already.

I found a thread discussing what I believe is likely a deeply related issue:
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/27436

Key takeaway there is that at least in that version of the GitLab product they hadn't found a great answer yet.  I decided to start doing some experimentation:

https://gitlab.com/mattbornski/gitlab-ci-exploration

I set up a whole bunch of environment variables in different formats to see which resulted in a dollar sign.

```sh
$ python3 audit_environment.py
DOLLA_DOUBLE_MIDSTRING = 1$234
DOLLA_QUAD_MIDSTRING = 1$$234
DOLLA_SINGLE_MIDSTRING_BACKSLASHED = 1\34
DOLLA_DOUBLE_MIDSTRING_BACKSLASHED = 1\\34
DOLLA_DOUBLE_MIDSTRING_LEADING_BACKSLASHED = 1\$234
DOLLA_QUAD_ENDSTRING = 1234$$
DOLLA_SINGLE_MIDSTRING_BACKSLASHED_DOUBLE_QUOTED = "1\34"
DOLLA_SINGLE_MIDSTRING_DOUBLE_QUOTED = "134"
DOLLA_SINGLE_MIDSTRING_BACKSLASHED_SINGLE_QUOTED = '1\34'
DOLLA_SINGLE_MIDSTRING = 134
Job succeeded
```

So, takeaway here:

- Double dollar signs result in a single dollar sign appearing in the environment variable accessible to your code in GitLab CI.  This can be repeated.
- Quoting passes through but does not impact the expansion/elision of the dollar sign
- Backslash passes through but does not impact the expansion/elision of the dollar sign

So your options look like:

- Put four dollar signs in the var that you set so that you get two in the environment in which you run
- Regenerate your keys so that they don't have problematic characters in them (a very real option that I have definitely availed myself of many times to avoid this rabbit hole)

For further exploration, here are a bunch more fun options to try: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/309791

Comment: I have seen the same on-going issue with git lab and mentioned the same in the description section. I tried your 4 $$$$ suggestion already and it is stripping all the 4 and appending 1.                                                                             Input : Ab1ab$$$$                                                                                                                        Output: AB1ab1.

Comment: Unfortunately, i cannot use your second option since the secret that i am trying to use is from a different  shared system across the company, which i do not have access or control to suggest changes.                                                                          The only workaround i can find so far is to store it base64 encoded and decode at CI time, i know which is not pretty

Comment: @maddie it's very interesting that it results in a `1`.  Are there any suspicious looking environment variables that have a dollar sign in the *name* ?

Comment: @maddie do you use a custom or specific runner for your CI?

Comment: @ mattbornski                                                                                                    
1. My exact varibale is sth like this "6ab@sh$$" numbers and letters changed , and my output would be 6ab@sh$. When i use "6ab@sh$$$$" the output is 6ab@sh1.                                                                                        
2.For the second question, i use couple of shared ci runners defined by using tags in my ci, out of which the available runner picks up my job.